# Which Map/Collection to use?

Tags: java, collections, hash

In the below key/value list "val3" is repeating for different keys. Which map suits best for such type of list.

I want "val3" should be stored only once with multiple keys pointing to it.

key1---->val1
key2---->val3
key3---->val3
key5---->val5
key6---->val3
key7---->val6
key8---->val3
key9---->val3

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "stored only once"?

Comment: "val3" should not be repeated in the memory for each key

Comment: The complete object, or just the reference? That's what I was looking for with "exactly". I assume you understand how references and objects work in Java, and that a map would only ever contain a *reference*, not an actual object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `Map` implementation will do. Every Java collection only holds references, not actual objects, so if you put the same object several times in a map, all the values will point to the same object. In other words changes made to `val3` through `key2` lookup will be reflected when looking up by any other key pointing to `val3`.

Consider simplified example:

```
VeryLarge v = new VeryLarge();
Map<Integer, VeryLarge> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(1, v);
map.put(2, v);
map.put(3, v);
```

Single `VeryLarge` instance is referenced by all `1`, `2` and `3` keys.

Comment: @thomasz String s1=new String("str1") and String s2=new String("str1") how to achieve this? values are same but different instances!

Comment: @Vasant: `s1 = "str1"; s2 = "str1"` - now they are equal, see also: http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/07/string-memory-internals.html

Answer (score 1):

As long as you ensure that you don't get values through `clone` operation or values aren't **immutable** objects (apart from `String` literals or `Integer.valueOf()`(values from -128 to 127 are caching and returned back from cache) which are exceptions), you'll end up with multiple keys pointing to the same concerned reference.

So you can use `HashMap` for instance, as @Tomasz Nurkiewicz has adviced.